# Guidance Request : SSO between CIviCRM & WordPress!

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php, authentication, sso

We've been using CiviCRM for a number of years and also running a blog on WordPress.

I can't find much information on setting up SSO / OAUTH / SAML / or even just custom CiviCRM | WP API to handshake and achieve a better user experience.
(I checked the CiviCRM API Doc and don't see user authentication)
I once setup SSO between Vanilla Forums 2 and a custom C# asp.net site and just don't see something like that available.

I did find this: (I wouldn't use Facebook SSO because of privacy offneses)
https://civicrm.org/sites/civicrm.org/files/SingleSignOnAccess-for-CiviCRM-Facebook-case.pdf

WordPress has alot of options for SSO plugins:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/single-sign-on/

Comment: You're probably not finding much because CiviCRM doesn't handle authentication at all. You'll have better luck either searching for how to share logins between two wordpress sites or looking/asking at wordpress.stackexchange.com. I'm assuming your CiviCRM site uses wordpress too. If it uses drupal or joomla then you'd still need to look elsewhere, but you'd search for sharing logins between wordpress and the other one, not CiviCRM.

Comment: Your right it's using Drupal, but I'm not in charge of it, just the WordPress side.

Comment: Ok thanks for replying. Hope you find something to share between drupal and wordpress!

Answer (score 1):

One option to look at that will work for Wordpress to Wordpress and Wordpress to Drupal and Drupal to Drupal is using SimpleSAMLphp and an appropriate plugin.

The Drupal SimpleSAMLphp module https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalauth4ssp provides hooks which you can use to populate data from CiviCRM if you want to share this between the sites. (Note - you need a drupal module for drupal and a drupal simplesamlphp module for simplesamlphp)

The Wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-saml-auth/ provides similarly the WP plugin has some filters you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved CiviCRM over to WordPress (same instance) you would have no problem, but as you have been running on Drupal for some while I expect that you'd have to change various things and it would change the user experience a bit so probably not the route you want to take.